# Flutter ask fro a flutter firestore multi env with dotenv example

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some problems to init my project for chrome

I run:

```
flutter run -d chrome --dart-define env=local
```

But the project stop load with the icon on the screen and i don't know why i have this error.

> Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"

[image: flutter code main and debug console]

I use flavor for android and iOS, but for web i don't know how to do multi env.

Is it possible to have a demo install for a flutter firebase firestore init with multi environment with dotenv package ?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)